# Is it possible to POST to a class method in Javascript (Ajax -> PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm handling a file-upload with a progress bar using Ajax, and currently I POST to an upload script:

```
          function uploadFile(revision) 
      {
          var file1 = _("fileToUpload").files[0];

          // FIXME: Developer Option
          alert(file1.name+" | "+file1.size+" | "+file1.type);

          var formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("fileToUpload", file1);
          formdata.append("revision", revision);
          var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
          ajax.open("POST", "../file_upload_parser.php");
          ajax.send(formdata);    
      }
```

However, if possible I want to move my upload into a class method (let's say there's a class called FileHandler and I want to be able to POST to it's upload() function.

**Would it be possible to POST it to the class's upload method?**

Obviously I want to be able to keep the functionality of a loading bar, and if anybody needs to view the source code for the Javascript, here's a link to where I essentially copy-pasta'd code and made a few changes (upload_form.html):

[JavaScript File Upload](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP)

Comment: There are no real classes in javascript, there are new instances, and it doesn't really make sense to use that for something like this ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking about making a class in javascript, I was just simply trying to POST to a class file that I created in PHP.

Comment: Posting to a class in PHP is the same as posting to any script, you catch the data and decide what to output

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you can't. What you can do is have a handler file for your classes, so for example say we have this PHP class,

```
<?php
class Car {     
    function getCarType() {
        return "Super Car";
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your handler file,

```
<?php
require_once 'Car.php';

if(isset($_POST['getCarType'])) {
     $car = new Car();
     $result = $car->getCarType();
}

echo $result;
?>
```

You'd post your AJAX request to the handler, you could make specific handlers for each request or you could have a generic AJAX handler, however that file could get quite big and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about javascript, it's about «how to properly route request in PHP?»
try to look at something like Symfony's Router :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html